# trying to get a table in position

Tags: texmaker

This is my first time writing something using latex, so pls be kind.
I want a 1 x 1 table to be displayed as basically the answer to a maths question, I'm using texmaker and so i know that to do it I just have to add the optional parameter [h] for "here". ive used this for the same assignment multiple times above and they work just fine, but for this one it always comes up either above or below the designated place where it should be. why is this occuring?
I have attached my code and also what I see on the preview. pls refer to the image attached:
I want the table to appear right under:"Since there are 2 options for the student for all 10 questions, there are $2^1{}^0$ possible ways to answer the quiz. So our answer would be:"

code:

```
`\item In how many ways can a student answer a 10 question TRUE/FALSE quiz? How many more ways can the student answer
```

the quiz if they are allowed to leave questions blank in order to avoid a penalty for a wrong answer?\

Since there are 2 options for the student for all 10 questions, there are $2^1{}^0$ possible ways to answer the quiz. So our answer would be:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
\textbf{1024} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}`
```

Comment: Also, i just found out that in [a4paper,11pt] its fine but in [a4paper,10pt] it is not. why is this happening?

Comment: Remove the table environment if you don't want the tabular to move away.

Comment: you should remove the `table` environment and `\centering` then the tabular will not move, but what is the point of a 1x1 table? you could replace all the posted code by `\fbox{\bfseries 1024}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for this information. I will remember to use it next time

Comment: @leandriis thank you